# $.fileDownload library works incorrect with sending array with "POST"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have following code:

```
$.fileDownload("url", {
  httpMethod: "POST"
  data:
    params: [{key: 1}, {key: 3}]
})
```

And server recive: `{"params"=>{"0"=>{"key"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"key"=>"3"}}}`, but it should be like this: `{"params"=>[{"key"=>"1"}, {"key"=>"3"}]}`

What i'm doing wrong?

I'm using Ruby On Rails on server side and AngularJS on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` will always be a hash. You cannot use an array as the top-level container.

If you want to pass multiple keys, use this structure:

```
params: { key: [1, 3] }
```